# Do we have $ \int_{A} \chi_B \mu = \mu(A) $ in a probability space?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Here I have a rather naive question concerning integral representation of probability measures. In general I have problems with it, so here there is a super basic setting:

- $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ probability space,
- $A, B \in \Sigma$,
- $\chi_B \in [0,1]^X$ indicator function of $B$ (measurable),
- $\int_X \chi_B \mu$.

---

***Problem:***
*Considering that $A \in \Sigma$ is arbitrary, can we proceed with the following equivalence:*
$$ \int_{A} \chi_B \mu = \mu(A) ?$$

---

**Questions:**

I think we can in general, but I am not sure why.

1. Is it true that we can?
2. If yes, why?

Any feedback as always it is greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: No, you have $\int_A 1_B d \mu = \int 1_A 1_B d \mu = \int 1_{A \cap B} d \mu = \mu (A \cap B)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I see the point, even if I miss the first equality (I know, I am really bad at this stuff). Could you expand a bit on it? That would be enormously appreciated.

Comment: The definition of $\int_A f d \mu $ is $\int 1_A \cdot f d \mu$. Then use $f = 1_B$.

Comment: Yep. Well, sorry for the rather easy question. Still, thanks a lot, because – as easy as it could seem to you – your feedback was extremely useful.

Comment: Glad to help. Frankly, I find working from abstract definitions very difficult (I am an engineer :-)), so I tend to think in terms of 'concrete' spaces first and then slowly generalise. I think it was Steinhaus who said that you have to 'earn the right to generalise'. For me, it is not an earned right, but a required rite of passage.

Comment: Nice (and true) quotation, and I also agree with your view. In both cases, more often than not I have the feeling that for me it is quite a long way to that point. Still, the best thing is not to give up, and it is always super-helpful to get feedbacks here, even on things that look trivial (even if I know that sometime those of you who gave them to me, really have to think there is something wrong about my backgrounds & fundamentals... and that's why I am always tempted to put the self-learning tag). Anyway, thanks a lot again! :-)

Comment: With mathematics, obvious means 'it can be proved by somebody' and trivial means 'it can be proved by me'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of an answer: 
$$
∫_A1_Bdμ=∫_X1_A1_Bdμ=∫_X1_{A∩B}dμ=μ(A∩B).
$$